# Get current username from File Directory

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to make my application save a file to the following location:

```
C:\Users\???\AppData\Local\Temp\
```

Although I'm having trouble with getting the current username, can anyone help out?

This is the code I'm using:

```
SaveFromResources("C:\Users\ ?? \AppData\Local\Temp\SysWOW.exe", My.Resources.SysWOW16)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ALLUSERSPROFILE")  'All Users Directory'
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile)) 'Current User Directory
```

For your case

```
Dim LocalAppData As String = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData)
MsgBox(LocalAppData)
```

LocalAppData will return

```
C:\Users\userName\AppData\Local\Temp\
```

Comment: See now.. LocalAppData will return the path..@user3381912

Answer (score 0):

Use `%HOMEPATH%.`

So:

```
CD %HOMEPATH%
```

Comment: So I would do this? C:\Users\%HOMEPATH%\AppData\Local\Temp\

Comment: Hmm, still no luck :/ any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Please note that this does not include the drive on which the home directory is located. For this, use `%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%`, which makes `"X:\Users\MyUser"` where X is the correct drive.

Answer (score 0):

you can also use System.Environment.UserName to get the user name. This would give your ???

Comment: can you check whether this is helpful

System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;